# Form input value in an ngFor generated table

Tags: html, input, angular, ngfor

I want to be able to submit a number for any player in the table.

I am generating a table with *ngFor in Angular2.
For each element in that table I add a form with an input field.

How can I submit and include the input value from those forms?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Value</th>
        <th>Bid</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="#player of players">
        <td>{{player.name}}</td>
        <td>{{player.value | currency:'GBP':true:'4.0-0'}}</td>
        <td>
            <form role="form" (submit)="onBid($event, player)">
                <input type="number" min={{player.value}} value={{player.value}}>
                <button type="submit">Bid</button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I haven't been able to submit and retrieve the value from the input box.
Doing it for a static form where I can define `id="inputname"` and `#inputname` and then add `inputname.value` to the `(submit)="onBid(inputname.value)"` works.

I've tried `adding id={{player.id}}` and `#{{player.id}}` but don't know how to add it to `onBid()`.

Comment: What do you mean by "submit and retrieve"? What's the problem with `(submit)="onBid(inputname.value)"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[working Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/xerfxa?p=preview)**

```
<td>
   <form role="form" (submit)="onBid($event, player, name.value)">
      <input type="number" #name  min={{player.value}} value={{player.value}}>
      <button type="submit">Bid</button>
   </form>
</td>
```

---

```
onBid(e,player,value) {
   player.inputValue=value; //<-----this will add new property to your existing object with input value.
   console.log(player);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, **#name** solved it! I thought it had to be unique and forgot to try that, I was so focused on generating a unique name for each form.

Comment: Welcome @user1134573.NP !

Comment: It didn't worked out for me in that way. **What if I have multiple rows of the input field used in an ngFor directive? And, how can I save/manipulate that in ts file as per need?**  Consider it as an array of players information in a table.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "post" the whole form, why don't you leverage `ngModel` bound to an array or an object.

Here is a sample with an array:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <form role="form" (submit)="onBid($event, player)">
    <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Value</th>
      <th>Bid</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="#player of players; #i=index">
      <td>{{player.name}}</td>
      <td>{{player.value | currency:'GBP':true:'4.0-0'}}</td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="bids[i]"
               min="{{player.value}}" value="{{player.value}}">
      </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <button type="submit">Bid</button>
    </form>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {
    this.players = [
      (...)
    ];
    this.bids = [];
  }

  onBid() {
    console.log(this.bids);
  }
}
```

and with an object:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <form role="form" (submit)="onBid($event, player)">
    <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Value</th>
      <th>Bid</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="#player of players; #i=index">
      <td>{{player.name}}</td>
      <td>{{player.value | currency:'GBP':true:'4.0-0'}}</td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="bids[player.name]"
               min="{{player.value}}" value="{{player.value}}">
      </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <button type="submit">Bid</button>
    </form>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {
    this.players = [
      (...)
    ];
    this.bids = {};
  }

  onBid() {
    console.log(this.bids);
  }
}
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/Ox4HmliuX3ESdf8JIZgr?p=preview.